Defining conditional independence between random vectors given a random vector
In my first probability course, I learned two separated definitions of expectation, one for the discrete case and other for the continuous case. Now I know that there exist random variables that are neither continuous nor discrete, and the more general definition of expectation is based on the cumulative distribution function.
In the same way, I want to have a general definition of conditional independence between two random vectors $X$ and $Y$ given a third random vector $Z$. My intuition says that this definition should be based on cumulative distribution functions, but I didn’t find any reference doing this (I only find definitions for the discrete and absolutely continuous cases).
I found something near to what I want only on Wikipedia (see 1 ). However, it is not clear for me if it makes sense to say “for all Z”.
For instance, let $Z_1$ be uniformly distributed on [0,1] and let $P(Z_2 = z | Z_1 = z) = 1$. In such a case, $Z = (Z_1,Z_2)$ belongs to the identity line with probability one. I don’t know if it makes sense to say that there exists a conditional distribution of something given $(Z_1 = 0.2, Z_2 = 0.6)$, for instance.
So, it seems that the equality should holds only for “some desirable values of $Z$”. But what values? I think that “values with non-null probability’’ is not a good answer, because, if $Z$ is absolutely continuous, then any point has zero probability.
In summary, my question is: how to define conditional independence between two random vectors given another random vector? Do you agree to use cumulative distribution functions in the definition? For what $Z$ values should equality occur?
Ps: I have a major in statistics. My background in mathematical statistics is weak, but I want to improve precisely in that. That's why I'm looking for a formal and general definition. I apologize if my question is too simple for someone with my background.
Thank you!

You will be able to answer your question and achieve your goal on improving mathematical statistics in a complete and thorough way by studying $\textbf{measure theoretical probability theory}$. If you do not study the theory, you will not be able to understand the formal and general definition you requested.

Thank you for your answer, @温泽海!However, I would be grateful if you could put here such definition.

Here is the formal definition you asked me to put here for. To understand the definition, please study measure theory and then probability theory. To achieve your goal of doing statistics, understanding these mathematical theories is mandatory.
Given a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and sub$\sigma$-algebras $G$, $\{F_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$, we say that the family of sub$\sigma$-algebras
$\{F_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is conditionally independent given $G$ if for every choice of positive integer $k$, every choice of indices $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k \in A$, and every choice of $\Lambda_j \in F_{\alpha_j}$, we always have, almost surely :
\begin{equation*}
P \{\bigcap_{j=1}^k \Lambda_j \mid G\} = \prod_{j=1}^k P \{\Lambda_j \mid G\}.
\end{equation*}
For random variables, they said to be conditionally independent if the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them are conditionally independent.

Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. I promise I will study measurement theory.
